# Code signing DLL files with Electron Builder

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I have a few .DLL files which are packaged together with the main .EXE file and are left unsigned.

In my case, these files are: ffmpeg.dll, libeay32.dll, libEGL.dll, libGLESv2.dll and sqlite3.dll.

I think that ffmpeg.dll, libEGL.dll, and libGLESv2.dll are Chromium and Node dependencies, whereas sqlite3.dll, libeay32.dll are dependencies of one of our dependencies.

Is there a reason why electron-builder ignores unsigned .DLL files, even those which are direct Electron dependencies?

Is there a way to include them in the code signing process?

Thanks!

Juan

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out this is already supported in `electron-builder` with `signDlls` parameter:
https://www.electron.build/configuration/win